# Baked texture blurry

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, image, texture-baking, blur

I'm new to Blender and I'm trying to bake my model. I watched a lot of tutorials and I think I'm ready to do it.
Wha't I'm doing is here working with blender internal:

- create uv map
- resize textures in the uv editor
- change the EWA filter size to 0.1 in the texture tab -> image sampling. This will render the model in a better way without blur effect
- bake my textures

But when I import the model in other softwares (using obj format) I have a blurry model, even if I reduced the EWA filter.
I tried a lot of parameters but the result is always blurry.
This is strange because changing the EWA filter give me a good result in rendering view.

Maybe the problem is the size of UV Map? I did also an image of 10'000 pixel square but the result didn't change. I tried also with little uv map like 1024 px.

Here some screenshots:

Blender Rendered View with EWA filter set default = 1

[image: Blender Rendered View with EWA filter set default = 1]

Blender Rendered View with EWA filter set to minimum = 0.1

[image: Blender Rendered View with EWA filter set to minimum = 0.1]

Exported model with baked texture : the result is blurry as before the modification of EWA filter

[image: Exported model with baked texture : the result is blurry as before the modification of EWA filter]

I want to obtain a baked textures result as in the second image with EWA = 0.1

Comment: Are you sure that this isn't a problem with the other software you are using?  For example if there are LOD/Mipmap settings that are incorrectly configured.

Comment: Hello, 
after some test I finally found that the problem was due to the software I'm using to import obj. 
thanks.